# How to show header names in Outlook 2013 message view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013 when a message is opened, the headers are shown like this (with different text sizes, plus a pictogram of the sender):

```
foo
bar
baz
```

How to make it look like in older versions, with names of each header:

```
From:    foo
To:      bar
Subject: baz
```

?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: you can't make it look like this, sorry.

Explanation: actually, you can but you really don't want to. You can create a custom form (or region) for IPM.Note that replaces the standard one. This way leads to huuuuge negative impact in all imaginable ways. Also, there are no known (to me) add-ins that help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/571874)

Comment: @Ramhound, everything is pretty clear and my post directly answers the question.

Comment: System generated that comment, because I selected a reason, when this answer appeared in the review queue.

Comment: @fixer1234: I'm pretty sure this can be upvoted by other users. I think you understand that currently there is no ms kb or something to be a first-party source. Either you believe/trust the answer or not. If you think I'm wrong, downvote the answer. If you know I'm right, upvote it. This is how it works.

Comment: Not sure why am I doing this, but I edited the answer. Thanks go to @fixer1234 =)